# Serving webpack generated CSS file via CDN in Heroku CI environment

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, webpack

I have an Node.JS Meteor app that I bundle with **webpack**, that generates a CSS file with a hash in the name: **[hash].bundle.css**. I can set the publicPath to the CDN domain:

```
output: {
  publicPath: 'https://xxx.cloudfront.com/',
},
```

On **Heroku** the bundle will be generated in the staging-environment and the generated **slug** will then be moved to the live-environment (including the css file).

When there is a change in the CSS, there will be a **new hash** in the staging-environment. When the site is opened (testing...) cloudfront will be asking the live-environment for that file, but the **Node.JS-server responses with the app-HTML**, that is issuing a not-found error on the browser.

### Idea: Making the CDN fallback to staging

This is recommended in ther heroku documentation. But since the app-server does not respond with a 404 http error, cloudfront will not look at the staging server.

### Problem: serving a 404 http error for missing files

This sound's not to difficult. [Meteor webapp](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/webapp) uses [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and I use [FlowRouter](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router) on the client side, so I can:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(FlowRouter.matchPath(req.url).route.name == 'not-found') {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end('Not found.');
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

But: there is many other `connectHandlers` that I would need to know, and make FileSystem checks. I tried going down that road, but it seems endless, maintenance intensive and not fail-proof.

### Idea: Using Meteor's `?meteor_css_resource=1`

There is a [Meteor specific treatment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/efc8a3525db6067bf1d381c033c6ac937c15d631/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js#L942) of a css file with a query parameter `xx.css?meteor_css_resource=1`, but that won't be counting as a 404 error for the CDN to make the request to staging again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking all available `connectHandlers`, we filter just the **`.css`** files.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const urlParts = url.parse(req.url)

  if(urlParts.pathname.endsWith('.css')) {
    res.writeHead(404)
    res.end('CSS file not found.')
  } else {
    return next()
  } 
}
```